# Labels not getting placed properly over flot bar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova, flot

I am developing an application using jquery mobile and flot charts.

In That i have 3 tabs.
I am displaying my chart on the first tab.But the weird thing which is happening is that if i plot the graph in the first tab then my labels get misplaced.Here is the fiddle [jsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/coderslay/Sp8MP/)

But if suppose i plot my graph in second or third tab then my charts are correct. My code is here [jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/coderslay/Sp8MP/3/)

why is this happening?

Comment: The problem is related to the `padding` value for the `ui-content` as i have been experimenting with your jsfiddles ... but trying to fix it is a different matter :-(

Comment: Are you sure it is related to padding?.Because it works for second tab.I am thinking that in the first tab the plotting starts even thought the document isn't ready.And the labels which are getting misplaced is dynamically adjusted as such depending upon the barwidth and height.

Comment: Im pretty new to flot but does seem very strange .... i updated your code to trigger drawing on the click of a button and when the chart was on tab one no labels were drawn .. worked fine for tab two !!! good luck !

Comment: Thanks Mate!!! for trying this confusing thing... My Head is spinining from about 4 hours :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.
I just need to change `plot.Offset()` to `plot.getPlotOffset()`
Then its working correctly.

**offset()** --
    Returns the offset of the plotting area inside the grid relative
    to the document, useful for instance for calculating mouse
    positions (event.pageX/Y minus this offset is the pixel position
    inside the plot).

**getPlotOffset()** --
    Gets the offset that the grid has within the canvas as an object
    with distances from the canvas edges as "left", "right", "top",
    "bottom". I.e., if you draw a circle on the canvas with the center
    placed at (left, top), its center will be at the top-most, left
    corner of the grid.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `plotOffset` calculation is different for your tabs and depends on whether container is visible or not. I think this is because jQuery can not calculate the height of the element which is hidden with `display: none`. In the first example `plotOffset` give you this numbers:

```
{left: 22, top: 41}
```

while for the second

```
{left: 7, top: 4}
```

When you then call `ctx.translate(plotOffset.left, plotOffset.top);` you will obviously have different lables position on the canvas.

The simpliest workaround is would be to normalize your translation with something like this:

```
ctx.translate(7, 3); // No need to care of plotOffset left and top
```

Use staticaly defined label margins instead of plotOffset values.

Updated demos:
http://jsfiddle.net/Sp8MP/5/ 
http://jsfiddle.net/Sp8MP/6/

Comment: Will hard coding this ctx.translate(7, 3); will affect different layouts? And why is the graphs in different tabs of different height?

Comment: by the way the values can still make the top labels go on top of the box edge: [jsfiddle.net/Sp8MP/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/Sp8MP/8/) or [disappear](http://jsfiddle.net/Sp8MP/9/) all together. That's probably a separate problem.