# How to add div dynamically in tabs using JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have an application which uses phonegap and jquery mobile and it has tabs like this

```
<div data-role="header">
    <div data-role="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tab-1" class="">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab-2" class="">Tab 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab-3" class="">Tab 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="content">
    <div id="tab-1">
        <h2>Here is the second tab</h2>       
    </div>

    <div id="tab-2">
        <h2>Here is the second tab</h2>
    </div>

    <div id="tab-3">
        <h2>Here is the third tab</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now i need to do the following things

1. How to add a div dynamically to any of the tab?
2. How to show progress bar for about 10 seconds and then display the result.

Comment: I am new to Javascrpting.For dynamically adding div i have seen some post but i am not able to understand.For Progress bar I read about .delay() and setTimeOut().

Comment: I would recommend you to ask questions one by one. For example I think I can answer your first question, but have no idea about the second one. So what happens now? Should I answer or shouldn't I?

Comment: Yup Please answer the First Question :P

Comment: Why would you want to show a progress bar for ten seconds? If you have to show one then just as long as the background process really runs.

Comment: Actually i am drawing some flot graphs and i want to show these graphs after a certain interval of time...

Comment: Why not just show 'em when they are ready?

Comment: Actually i am facing some issue while plotting at the time when the document is ready.. See here i posted it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428132/labels-not-getting-placed-properly-over-flot-bar-chart/9462005#9462005

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dynamically add DOM elements with jQuery like this:

```
$('#container').append("<div></div>");
```

For jQuery-Mobile, you'd have to call `refresh` on any library specific constructs, such as `listviews`.